# How to put floating points in LUA

Tags: lua

I would like to know how to put points in large numbers

exemple:

```
local n = 100000
```

i need print this:

```
local n = 100.000
```

with points

thanks

Comment: "floating point" is something very different. You want [thousands separators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Digit_grouping). Do you need a way to write them in code (like your example says), or to print them to a user?

Comment: oh sorry :(, but yeah, i need separators for huge numbers